# Restarurar Datos de DataBase NO Preexistentes SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo registros actuales en una Base de Datos llamada **A_Restaurar** Tengo a Pedro, Jose ,saul, Mengano, Fulano y Sutano en fin mas de mil registros de Cuentas Viejas quiero restaurar todos esos datos a una Nueva BaseDatos llamada **EN_USO** pero esta tiene algunos registros con el mismo Usuario, no deseo copiar 2 Veces el mismo registro ¿Como puedo hacer esto sin que me repita el mismo registro?

```
INSERT [DASEDATOS_En USO].[dbo].[EN_USO](       
        [UserID],[Pw],[JoinDate],[Admin],[AdminLevel],[UseQueue],[Status],[Leave],[LeaveDate],[UserType],[UserIp],[ModiIp],[ModiDate],[Point],[Enpassword],[Birth],[email],[Activation],[pais],[mes],[dia],[anio],[nombre],[apellido],[MotivoBan],[GS],[Contador],[Activo],[FechaDuper],[FinBan],[Verifi],[Protector],[Staff],[DEV],[Email_viejo],[UserID_Viejo],[Point2])
SELECT  [UserID],[Pw],[JoinDate],[Admin],[AdminLevel],[UseQueue],[Status],[Leave],[LeaveDate],[UserType],[UserIp],[ModiIp],[ModiDate],150000 ,[Enpassword],[Birth],[email],[Activation],[pais],[mes],[dia],[anio],[nombre],[apellido],[MotivoBan],[GS],[Contador],[Activo],[FechaDuper],[FinBan],[Verifi],[Protector],[Staff],[DEV],[Email_viejo],[UserID_Viejo],15000 
FROM [DASEDATOS_Arestaurar].[dbo].[A_Restaurar]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `Where` con la clausula `NOT EXISTS` solo hara el ingreso de los datos si el `UserId` no existe en la tabla donde haras el `Insert`. (Al responder estaba suponiendo que el `UserId` es la clave unica de la tabla)

```
INSERT [DASEDATOS_En USO].[dbo].[EN_USO](       
        [UserID],[Pw],[JoinDate],[Admin],[AdminLevel],[UseQueue],[Status],[Leave],[LeaveDate],[UserType],[UserIp],[ModiIp],[ModiDate],[Point],[Enpassword],[Birth],[email],[Activation],[pais],[mes],[dia],[anio],[nombre],[apellido],[MotivoBan],[GS],[Contador],[Activo],[FechaDuper],[FinBan],[Verifi],[Protector],[Staff],[DEV],[Email_viejo],[UserID_Viejo],[Point2])
SELECT  [UserID],[Pw],[JoinDate],[Admin],[AdminLevel],[UseQueue],[Status],[Leave],[LeaveDate],[UserType],[UserIp],[ModiIp],[ModiDate],150000 ,[Enpassword],[Birth],[email],[Activation],[pais],[mes],[dia],[anio],[nombre],[apellido],[MotivoBan],[GS],[Contador],[Activo],[FechaDuper],[FinBan],[Verifi],[Protector],[Staff],[DEV],[Email_viejo],[UserID_Viejo],15000 
FROM [DASEDATOS_Arestaurar].[dbo].[A_Restaurar]

where NOT EXISTS (select userid 
from [DASEDATOS_En USO].[dbo].[EN_USO] a 
where a.userid = [DASEDATOS_Arestaurar].[dbo].[A_Restaurar].userid
)
```